# Vmware Xorg error compiling keymap?

Tags: xorg, vmware

I've upgraded from Opensuse 12.2 M3 to 12.2 Beta 1 and X is broken. Startup hangs after mysqld with a black screen. But I can use a console and when I try to manually start X it gives me the error compiling keymap? I have already tried to reinstall xkbcomp to no avail. Running Xorg -configure doesn't help either. It gives error message numbers of screens not the same like numbers of devices? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running:

```
zypper install-new-recommends.
```